# How to populate my base Customer with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

see my class structure first.

```
public class CustomerBase
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }

}

public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
    public virtual List<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Customer { get; set; } 

}

public class TestDBContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDBContext()
        : base("name=TestDBContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

now this way i am trying to populate my customer base but getting error.

```
    var bsCustomer1 = (from c in db.Customer
                       where (c.CustomerID == 2)
                       select new
                       {
                           CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                           FirstName = c.FirstName,
                           LastName = c.LastName,
                           Addresses = (from ad in c.Addresses
                                        where (ad.IsDefault == true)
                                        from cts in ad.Contacts
                                        where (cts != null && cts.IsDefault == true)
                                        select ad).ToList(),
                       }).ToList()
            .Select(x => new CustomerBase
            {
                CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                Address1 = x.Addresses.Select(a => a.Address1).SingleOrDefault(),
                Address2 = x.Addresses.Select(a => a.Address2).SingleOrDefault(),
                Phone = x.Addresses.Select(c => c.Contacts.Select(cd => cd.Phone).SingleOrDefault()),
                Fax = x.Addresses.Select(c => c.Contacts.Select(cd => cd.Fax).SingleOrDefault())
            }).ToList();
```

as per my situation a single customer may have multiple address but there should be one default one which i am pulling. a single address may have multiple contacts details but there should be one default one which i am pulling.

address1,address2, Phone and Fax are in base customer class. i want to pull single data from address and contacts tables based on **isdefault** is true and populate my customer. i am not very good in **linq**. so not being able to compose the query. please help me to compose it. thanks

Comment: when you getting the Address1(or Address2), try to use `Address1 = x.Addresses.First(a => a.IsDefault).Address1`. It will take the first address which `IsDefault == true` for Address1.

Comment: what is your error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, guess it may fit about your request.

```
 var bsCustomer1 = db.Customer.Where(p => p.CustomerID == 2)
        .Select(x => new CustomerBase
        {
            CustomerID = x.CustomerID,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            Address1 = x.Addresses.First(a => a.IsDefault).Address1,
            Address2 = x.Addresses.First(a => a.IsDefault).Address2,
            Phone = x.Addresses.First(a => a.IsDefault).Contacts.First(c => c.IsDefault).Phone),
            Fax = x.Addresses.First(a => a.IsDefault).Contacts.First(c => c.IsDefault).Fax)
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: if i give this clause `db.Customer.Where(p => p.CustomerID == 2 && p.CustomerID == 1)` then multiple customer will return. just tell me does your above code can handle when multiple customer will return? do we need to change in code to handle multiple customer ? please guide. thanks

Comment: sorry for my late reply. if you just want to select single Customer: `db.Customer.First(p => p.CustomerID == 2)`, above code can handle multiple customers. Because ` db.Customer.Where(p => p.CustomerID == 2)` equals `from p in db.Customer where p.CustomerID == 2 select p`.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your actual meaning when you say: "i want to pull single data from address and contacts tables based on isdefault is true and populate my customer" that could mean two things:

1. I want to project a new object
2. I want to UPDATE the backing database.

Okay a few things about EF:

1. You have a context for CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete) statements to the database.
2. The Context knows all the objects you identified in the database when setting up the EF file.
3. The t4 templates are created for entity context and the entity name itself and generate the context reference in the previous steps as well as create POCO class objects.

To create NEW objects you don't have to reference the object above it or below it.  You just need to create it and then update the database with it.

So for an example of EF let's say I have two database tables:

I have a table tePerson that has fields: PersonId, FirstName, LastName, OrderId. This table has values

```
1   Brett   X 1
2   Emily   X 2
4   Ryan    Y 1
10  Mark    Z 1
```

OrderId is a foreign Key to a table teOrder with only has two fields: OrderId and Description.

```
1   Shirt
2   Dress
```

And my POCO objects generated from the T4 are:

```
public partial class tePerson
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual teOrder teOrder { get; set; }
}
```

It is important to note that that 'virtual teOrder' points to another POCO for me like this:

```
public partial class teOrder
{
    public teOrder()
    {
        this.tePersons = new HashSet<tePerson>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tePerson> tePersons { get; set; }
}
```

Example for just projecting and for updating the database from the context as well as updating the database below.  The key thing to remember is that objects when doing 'selects' with EF are not realized till you do a method like 'ToList()' to make them concrete.  Else they are context db set which you cannot chain off of.

```
public class OtherPerson
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string PersonLongName { get; set; }
  public teOrder Order { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var context = new TesterEntities())
  {
    //Say I just want to project a new object with a select starting from orders and then traversing up.  Not too hard
    var newObjects = context.teOrders.Where(order => order.OrderId == 1)
      //SelectMan will FLATTEN a list off of a parent or child in a one to many relationship
      .SelectMany(peopleInOrderOne => peopleInOrderOne.tePersons)
      .ToList()
      .Select(existingPerson => new OtherPerson
      {
        PersonId = existingPerson.PersonId,
        PersonLongName = $"{existingPerson.FirstName} {existingPerson.LastName}",
        Order = existingPerson.teOrder
      })
      .ToList();

    newObjects.ForEach(newPerson => Console.WriteLine($"{newPerson.PersonId} {newPerson.PersonLongName} {newPerson.Order.Description}"));

    // Just an action clause to repeat find items in my context, the important thing to note is that y extends teOrder which is another POCO inside my POCO
    Action<string, List<tePerson>> GetOrdersForPeople = (header, people) => 
    {
      Console.WriteLine(header);
      people.ForEach(person => Console.WriteLine($"{person.FirstName} {person.LastName} {person.teOrder.Description}"));
      Console.WriteLine();
    };

    //I want to look at a person and their orders.  I don't have to do multiple selects down, lazy loading by default gives me a child object off of EF
    GetOrdersForPeople("First Run", context.tePersons.ToList());


    //Say I want a new order for a set of persons in my list?
    var newOrder = new teOrder { Description = "Shoes" };
    context.teOrders.Add(newOrder);
    context.SaveChanges();

    //Now I want to add the new order
    context.tePersons.SingleOrDefault(person => person.PersonId == 1).teOrder = newOrder;
    context.SaveChanges();

    //I want to rexamine now
    GetOrdersForPeople("After changes", context.tePersons.ToList());

    //My newOrder is in memory and I can alter it like clay still and the database will know if I change the context
    newOrder.Description = "Athletic Shoes";
    context.SaveChanges();

    GetOrdersForPeople("After changes 2", context.tePersons.ToList());

    //Say I want to update a few people with new orders at the same time
    var peopleBesidesFirst = context.tePersons.Where(person => person.PersonId != 1).ToList();
    var firstPersonInList = context.tePersons.Where(person => person.PersonId == 1).ToList();

    var newOrders = new List<teOrder> {
      new teOrder { Description = "Hat", tePersons = peopleBesidesFirst },
      new teOrder { Description = "Tie", tePersons = firstPersonInList }
      };

    context.teOrders.AddRange(newOrders);
    context.SaveChanges();

    GetOrdersForPeople("After changes 3", context.tePersons.ToList());
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```